# Batch job - violate constraint temporarily

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

Let's think about a column with a unique constraint and following values:

```
Col1
1
2
3
```

Now I want to change those values in a batch job to following:

```
Col1
2
3
4
```

The result is, as soon as I change 1 to 2, this violates the unique constraint and the batch job is stopped. Although, after finishing the batch job, the constraint would be fulfilled again.

How do I solve that problem?

**Use case**

I'm trying to rename a list of files in the media store via `contentResolver.applyBatch(MediaStore.AUTHORITY, operations)` and this throws an constraint violation exception...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such case that renaming elements might cause collisions on a unique column, you need to apply the transformation in a safe order.

Basically instead of asking the content provider to perform the following operations

```
rename 1 → 2
rename 2 → 3
rename 3 → 4
```

You should ask

```
rename 3 → 4
rename 2 → 3
rename 1 → 2
```

Which always satisfies the unique constraint.

Also even without the unique constraint, the first method would potentially rename everything to 4

Comment: Shouldn't the transaction take care of the potential renaming issue? But you're right, it makes more sense to sort the operations beforehand, that solves all problems, did not think about that.

Comment: No, the transaction is just a mechanism to make changes safe. A transaction has no mean to know that your columns are gonna be ok should you go to the end of all the operations.

Comment: I thought the transaction may distingiush between an old and new value and could check old values only until the transaction is committed. Thanks for helping